Incremental computation of total value over dates and groups
Here is my dataframe.
There is a date index and there are 4 symbols for each date.
I want to loop over each date for each symbol.
The 'quantity' column is calculated based on the 'tot_value' of the previous date. The 'tot_value' is computed for a specific date and is common for all symbols. The 'value' column varies for each symbol for each date.
It is an issue with the way I am using shift here. It does not reference the previous date value.
Instead it uses the default value of tot_value that I use while populating the dataframe.
However, in the final result the tot_value is getting computed correctly.
I am new to python and would appreciate any help with this loop.
dataframe
Here is my code.
import pandas as pd

# create the dataframe 
data = {'symbol': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'date':['05/06/2024','05/06/2024','05/06/2024','05/06/2024',
                               '05/07/2024','05/07/2024','05/07/2024','05/07/2024',
                               '05/08/2024','05/08/2024','05/08/2024','05/08/2024',
                               '05/09/2024','05/09/2024','05/09/2024','05/09/2024'],
       'tot_value': [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000,1000, 1000, 1000, 1000,1000, 1000, 1000, 1000,1000, 1000, 1000, 1000],
       'mult': [1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3,1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7,1.8, 1.9, 2, 2.1,2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5],
       'quantity': [0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0],
       'value': [0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0],
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(['date'], inplace = True)
symbols = df['symbol'].unique()

# loop by date index and symbol
for ind in df.index.unique():
    for symbol in symbols:
        df['quantity'][ind] = df['tot_value'][ind].shift(1) * df['mult'][ind]
        df['value'][ind] = df['quantity'][ind] * 5

    g = df.groupby('date')['value'].sum()
    df['tot_value'][ind] = g.sum()
    
df


Here is the expected output.
Calculations:
date = 5/6
There is no tot_value for a previous date so the quantity column is NaN. Hence the value is also NaN. And tot_value = default value of 1,000.
date = 5/7
tot_value for previous date = 1,000.
The quantity for this date is based on the tot_value of 1,000.
Once the quantity is calculated the value calc is straightforward.
tot_value for 5/7 = tot_value for 5/6 + sum of value for the 4 symbols on 5/7.
tot_value for 5/7 = 1,000 + sum(7,000 + 7,500 + 8,000 + 8,500) = 32,000
date = 5/8
tot_value for previous date = 32,000.
The quantity for this date is based on the tot_value of 32,000.
Once the quantity is calculated the value calc is straightforward.
tot_value for 5/8 = tot_value for 5/7 + sum of value for the 4 symbols on 5/8.
tot_value for 5/8 = 32,000 + sum(288,000 + 304,000 + 320,000 + 336,000) = 1,280,000.




symbol
tot_value (expected)
mult
quantity (expected)
value (expected)




date







5/6/2024
A
1,000
1
NaN
NaN


5/6/2024
B
1,000
1.1
NaN
NaN


5/6/2024
C
1,000
1.2
NaN
NaN


5/6/2024
D
1,000
1.3
NaN
NaN


5/7/2024
A
32,000
1.4
1,400
7,000


5/7/2024
B
32,000
1.5
1,500
7,500


5/7/2024
C
32,000
1.6
1,600
8,000


5/7/2024
D
32,000
1.7
1,700
8,500


5/8/2024
A
1,280,000
1.8
57,600
288,000


5/8/2024
B
1,280,000
1.9
60,800
304,000


5/8/2024
C
1,280,000
2
64,000
320,000


5/8/2024
D
1,280,000
2.1
67,200
336,000


5/9/2024
A
61,440,000
2.2
2,816,000
14,080,000


5/9/2024
B
61,440,000
2.3
2,944,000
14,720,000


5/9/2024
C
61,440,000
2.4
3,072,000
15,360,000


5/9/2024
D
61,440,000
2.5
3,200,000
16,000,000



expected output

You say that you compute the quantity based on the previous date, but use the previous symbol in the loop. What is the exact expected output?

Hello, so for date 5/7/24, for all 4 symbols, I want to use the tot_value as of 5/6.  This is used to calculate the quantity and value for 5/7.

That's unclear, please be explicit, break down the row-by-row computation for one symbol and provide the exact expected output given this input. I had a quick try and got very different results

Sure thing. Here is the table with the expected output.
(not sure how to paste images). Hope this is clear.
symbol tot_value (expected) mult quantity (expected) "value
(expected)"
date
5/6/2024 A  1,000  1  NaN   NaN
5/6/2024 B  1,000  1.1  NaN   NaN
5/6/2024 C  1,000  1.2  NaN   NaN
5/6/2024 D  1,000  1.3  NaN   NaN
5/7/2024 A  32,000  1.4  1,400   7,000
5/7/2024 B  32,000  1.5  1,500   7,500
5/7/2024 C  32,000  1.6  1,600   8,000
5/7/2024 D  32,000  1.7  1,700   8,500

Please [edit] the question with this text output (better than images). And don't forget to demonstrate how you would manually compute the first few rows.

Thank you very much for that tip.  I've added the calc steps on the question.  Hope this helps.

Thanks, that's clear, see the answer below. Be aware that it's a very unconventional use of pandas!

Your computation is inherently iterative, therefore a loop is a valid approach.
This is however not the classical type of pandas operation (usually vectorized).
One option, assuming the data is sorted by date, then symbol, would be to loop over a groupby (ignoring the first date):
# initial total
tot = df['tot_value'].iloc[0]

dates = df.index.unique()

for d, g in df.loc[dates[1]:].groupby('date', sort=False):
    qty = tot*g['mult']
    val = qty*5
    tot += val.sum()
    df.loc[d, 'quantity'] = qty
    df.loc[d, 'value'] = val
    df.loc[d, 'tot_value'] = tot

Output:
           symbol  tot_value  mult  quantity     value
date                                                  
05/06/2024      A       1000   1.0         0         0
05/06/2024      B       1000   1.1         0         0
05/06/2024      C       1000   1.2         0         0
05/06/2024      D       1000   1.3         0         0
05/07/2024      A      32000   1.4      1400      7000
05/07/2024      B      32000   1.5      1500      7500
05/07/2024      C      32000   1.6      1600      8000
05/07/2024      D      32000   1.7      1700      8500
05/08/2024      A    1280000   1.8     57600    288000
05/08/2024      B    1280000   1.9     60800    304000
05/08/2024      C    1280000   2.0     64000    320000
05/08/2024      D    1280000   2.1     67200    336000
05/09/2024      A   61440000   2.2   2816000  14080000
05/09/2024      B   61440000   2.3   2944000  14720000
05/09/2024      C   61440000   2.4   3072000  15360000
05/09/2024      D   61440000   2.5   3200000  16000000


That's amazing!!! This works perfectly, thank you very much @mozway.
I don't think I fully understand how the loop is working and I have a couple questions if you don't mind.
We are only grouping by date and not by symbol, so how does it know to update the correct symbol and date combo.
And secondly, on this line 'qty = tot*g['mult']', how does it know to use the tot_value from the previous date without using something like shift. It is using the correct value but from the code it is not super clear to me how it is working.

It doesn't "know" how to align the symbols, which is why a prerequisite is to always have the same order (ABCD). If you don't, a workaround might be to also set the symbol as secondary indez level. The total value is updated in the loop (+=). shift  would be used if the computation was vectorized, which is not the case here.
